# Enabling arch:SSE2 makes program slower

Tags: c++, sse

On Visual Studio 2010, when I enable enhanced instruction sets on the following code, the execution time is actually increased.

```
void add(float * input1, float * input2, float * output, int size)
{
    for(int iter = 0; iter < size; iter++)
    {
        output[iter] = input1[iter] * input2[iter];
    }
}

int main()
{

    const int SIZE = 10000000;
    float *in1 = new float[SIZE];
    float *in2 = new float[SIZE];
    float *out = new float[SIZE];
    for(int iter = 0; iter < SIZE; iter++)
    {
        in1[iter] = std::rand();
        in2[iter] = std::rand();
        out[iter] = std::rand();
    }
    clock_t start = clock();
    for(int iter = 0; iter < 100; iter++)
    {
        add(in1, in2, out, SIZE);
    }
    clock_t end = clock();
    double time = difftime(end,start)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I am consistently getting about `2.0` seconds for `time` variable with SSE2 enabled, but about `1.7` seconds when it is "Not Set".  I am building on Windows 7 64bit, VS 2010 professional, Release configuration, Optimize for speed.

Is there any explanation for why enabling SSE causes longer execution time?

Comment: Have you looked at the generated assembly to see if it is even using any SSE instructions?

Comment: Are you doing this with a debug build or a release build ?

Comment: @RetiredNinja I don't really know assembly very well, but I can confirm that it is using the register needed for SSE (xmm1 and xmm0 to be exact) only on the version compile with SSE enabled.

Comment: Will `new float[SIZE];` provide properly aligned data (aligned for SSE, I mean)?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes It shouldn't matter. MSVC doesn't auto-vectorize. I've seen this situation a few times before. Since MSVC doesn't vectorize, SSE isn't any better than x87 FPU. So slight differences can make either one a tiny bit faster.

Comment: These kinds of result are somewhat tightly coupled with your processor. Is it slower with all tested processors, or just with your own ? (and what processor btw?). I would get huge differences between AMD and Intel for some SSE instructions (especially precaching).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an overhead in SSE code for moving values into and from the SSE registers, which may outweigh the performance benefits of SSE if you are only doing very few, simple calculations as is the case with your example.

Also note that this overhead becomes significantly larger if your data is not 16-byte aligned.

Comment: This isn't relevant in this case because MSVC doesn't vectorize. So it simply uses SSE registers in place of x87 FPU. There is no "moving around". Similarly, alignment only comes to play with vector SSE - which MSVC does not generate by itself.

Comment: I have used SSE compiler intrinsics before and have noticed a speedup, so if you have to do it explicitly to use SSE, then what is the point of using the arch:SSE compiler option in the first place?

Comment: @Mystical: Good point, I didn't actually know that MSVC doesn't vectorize at all. The documentation says though, that it may use a mixture of x87 and SSE2 code, which could cause some moving (although I can hardly imagine the compiler messing that up in such a simple example). The only way to be sure is of course to examine the assembly.

Comment: @JAKE6459 On x64, you get the benefit of 8 additional registers. As for x86, I suppose the code is somewhat simpler since SSE is more flexible than x87 (there's no need for `xchg` and garbage like that). But whether or not it produces any speedup is very situational.

Answer (score 2):

IMO, it is often not a good idea to rely on the compiler to do these optimisations. Your code should run faster (unless the compiler already does it for you, which however does not seem to be the case). I suggest to

1 make sure your array is 16byte aligned

2 use SSE intrinsics in your inlined add function:

```
#include <xmmintrin.h>
inline void add(const float * input1, const float * input2, float * output, int size)
{
   // assuming here that 
   // - all 3 arrays are 16-byte aligned
   // - size is a multiple of 4
   for(int iter = 0; iter < size; iter += 4)
     _mm_store_ps( output+iter, _mm_mul_ps( _mm_load_ps(input1+iter),
                                            _mm_load_ps(input2+iter) ) );
}
```

if this does not produce faster code, then indeed the loading and storing create too much overhead for a single multiplication operation.